# Effect of 'myObj = [[[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease] retain];'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, memory-management

I've just downloaded the [Facebook iOS SDK](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) and I noticed that in the sample code that comes with the SDK whenever it creates an instance of the Facebook class it does it like this:

```
_facebook = [[[[Facebook alloc] init] autorelease] retain];
```

where `_facebook` is a member variable of the calling object (i.e. not a local variable).

Can anyone explain exactly what's the point of autoreleasing and then retaining it?

Comment: Hmm, think I'd better uninstall the Facebook app.  They clearly do not understand what they are doing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It effectively does nothing beyond consuming some cycles and memory.

Or, more precisely, in a correctly written application, it does nothing.   In an incorrectly written application, it might mask a bug by lengthening the lifespan of the `_facebook` object.  However, it isn't a real fix.

I found a similar line of code in http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/sample/DemoApp/Classes/DemoAppViewController.m   If that is what you are referring to then, yes, it is nonsense.

Comment: The alternative theory is that it's a symptom of memorization without understanding. “To create an object, I must write [[[ClassName alloc] init] autorelease]; to hold onto it; I must retain it.” Only the author of the statement knows for sure.

Comment: Running blame on that file attributes it to one dev, maybe someone should send an email asking for clarification on Github ;) http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blame/master/sample/DemoApp/Classes/DemoAppViewController.m

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought... but being in the "official" Facebook SDK I thought maybe the original developer knew something I didn't, so I figured I'd ask. Thanks for your input.

Comment: "official" doesn't always mean "best".

Comment: Added a comment on the actual line on Github: http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/8a1b923b39be8215857dd2b74e48e77a9e54bbaa#commitcomment-138182

Comment: Also you should really be using ARC these days, and whatever that dance was trying to "fix", you can't do on ARC, so it forces you to do memory management right, with no fragile hacks.

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible that the code you found was just sloppy, that pattern DOES have a meaning.

"alloc, autorelease, retain" implies that the object is referenced in two places:

- As a return value on the call stack (autorelease style)
- By the FB SDK itself (the 'retain')

This matters if the two references can be released independently.  For example, if the SDK can release its reference BEFORE the call stack has completed and drained the autorelease pool.  Ok, this is pretty nuanced; what do I mean?

Consider these cases:

**A) the actual code**

```
_facebook = [[[[Facebook alloc] init] autorelease] retain];
```

*_facebook now has a retain count of 2, and expects 2 calls to 'release': 1 from whoever called "retain", and 1 at some point in the future when the NSAutoreleasePool drains.*

**B) the simple "alternative" proposed (NOT equivalent)**

```
_facebook = [[Facebook alloc] init];
```

*_facebook has a retain count of 1 and will be destroyed when 'release' is called (potentially a big problem if the autorelease pool hasn't drained yet and the call stack is still using the object)*

**Why does this matter? Imagine some code like this:**

```
@implementation (Thinger)
+(id) make_new_thing
{
    return my_copy_of_thing = [[[[Thing alloc] init] autorelease] retain];
}
+(id) forget_about_thing
{
    if (my_copy_of_thing != nil) {
        [my_copy_of_thing release];
        my_copy_of_thing = nil;
    }
}
@end


void foo() {
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    id thing = [Thinger make_new_thing];
    [Thinger forget_about_thing];
    ...
    [thing useThing]; // implementation B would break here !
    [pool drain];
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, it is definitely *not* convention to ever write `[[[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease] retain]`. Rather it would be convention for the above `+make_new_thing` method to return a completely new instance of an autoreleased object (i.e., `return [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease]`) and not keep reference to the old one. It would be very bad design to have a "create" method that could potentially deallocate objects previously created with it on each call.

Comment: Yes, the example I gave was pretty artificial.   It's "correct" though.  My make_new_thing method calls "release" because it is giving up it's "my_copy_of_thing" reference.  It thus only "deallocates previously created objects" if there are no other references to those objects.

Comment: Sorry, but no, it's actually not correct. The fact that one would have to write `...alloc] init] autorelease] retain]` is a sign that the design *itself* is incorrect. There are better ways of designing this sort of functionality that would avoid both crazy memory management and bizarre side effects from the create method.

Comment: I make no statements about the elegance of the code and/or design patterns.  My point is only to note that contrary to the original response, there _IS_ a significant functional difference between <code>...autorelease] retain]</code> and just returning the value back to the caller.  The implication of that <code>retain</code> call in the original post is that the "_facebook" variable _OWNS_ a ref to that object and should prevent it from being deallocated.